# Button sound in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, button

How can I add a sound to a lightning button in LWC?

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
const audio = new Audio("https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/387");

export default class GetRandomQuotes extends LightningElement {
    sound = audio;
    onClickHandler(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/389327/edit) your question to add what happens (e.g., *exact* error text, *exact* unexpected results) when you run the above code.

Answer (score 9):

What you're likely experiencing is a limitation imposed by [Salesforce CSP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp.htm). In order to make it work, you need to [Manage CSP Trusted Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/csp_trusted_sites.htm). Go to Setup | CSP Trusted Sites, and add the site to enable access to the media files. Outside of Salesforce, LWC has no problem loading and playing the click sound.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/vi2hJKDvsZKtnugfGP8J/src/getRandomQuotes.js?p=stories).